# How to populate vector of structs from threads?

Tags: rust

I try to reproduce https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std_misc/threads/testcase_mapreduce.html but for structs.

```
let mut data: Vec<SomeStruct> = Vec::new();
```

further I iterate over csv file, map result to SomeStruct and try to populate vector from threads:

```
for result in rdr.records() {
    let record = result?;
    
    let map_some_struct = |new_record: csv::StringRecord| -> SomeStruct {
        let result = SomeStruct{};
        result
    };

    let some_struct = map_some_struct(record);
    data.push(thread::spawn(move || -> SomeStruct {
        some_struct
    }));
}
```

after that I try to repeat doc case but it doesn't work for me:

```
let final_result = data_iter().map(|c| c.join().unwrap());
```

with errors:

```
     data.push(thread::spawn(move || -> SomeStruct {
     |  ______________----_^
     | |              |
     | |              arguments to this function are incorrect
63   | |             some_struct
64   | |         }));
     | |__________^ expected struct `SomeStruct`, found struct `JoinHandle`

    no method named `join` found for struct `SomeStruct` in the current scope

    cannot index into a value of type `Map<std::vec::IntoIter<SomeStruct>, _>`
```

How can I populate vector of structs in right "rusty" way?

Comment: This looks like a perfect job for [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.collect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your minimal reproducible example is incomplete, please provide a complete one next time.

Here is one I reconstructed:

```rust
use std::{error::Error, thread};

struct Rdr;
impl Rdr {
    fn records(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Result<StringRecord, Box<dyn Error>>> {
        [Ok(StringRecord), Ok(StringRecord), Ok(StringRecord)].into_iter()
    }
}

struct StringRecord;
struct SomeStruct {}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let rdr = Rdr;

    let data: Vec<SomeStruct> = vec![];

    for result in rdr.records() {
        let record = result?;

        let map_some_struct = |_new_record: StringRecord| -> SomeStruct {
            let result = SomeStruct {};
            result
        };

        let some_struct = map_some_struct(record);
        data.push(thread::spawn(move || -> SomeStruct { some_struct }));
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
    --> src/main.rs:27:19
     |
27   |         data.push(thread::spawn(move || -> SomeStruct { some_struct }));
     |              ---- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `SomeStruct`, found struct `JoinHandle`
     |              |
     |              arguments to this function are incorrect
     |
     = note: expected struct `SomeStruct`
                found struct `JoinHandle<SomeStruct>`
note: associated function defined here
    --> /home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:1831:12
     |
1831 |     pub fn push(&mut self, value: T) {
     |            ^^^^
```

Now there are several things wrong with your code.

- All the work (I assume the actual work is done in the `map_some_struct` method) is done in the main thread. The spawned threads do nothing but move the result back.
- You never join the threads. That's what your error actually means, you are not writing a result into the `data` vector, but instead `JoinHandle`s of running threads. You need to join those handles before you get the actual result. This is also shown in the link you posted to the "Rust By Example" book.

With those two fixed, here's a working version:

```rust
use std::{error::Error, thread};

struct Rdr;
impl Rdr {
    fn records(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Result<StringRecord, Box<dyn Error>>> {
        [Ok(StringRecord), Ok(StringRecord), Ok(StringRecord)].into_iter()
    }
}

struct StringRecord;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SomeStruct {}

fn map_some_struct(_new_record: StringRecord) -> SomeStruct {
    let result = SomeStruct {};
    result
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let rdr = Rdr;

    let mut children = vec![];

    for result in rdr.records() {
        let record = result?;

        children.push(thread::spawn(move || {
            let some_struct = map_some_struct(record);
            some_struct
        }));
    }

    let final_result = children
        .into_iter()
        .map(|c| c.join().unwrap())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    println!("{:?}", final_result);

    Ok(())
}
```

```
[SomeStruct, SomeStruct, SomeStruct]
```

---

That said, there's a much easier and faster way of achieving what you are trying to do here. It's called [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon).

Rayon is a library that solves all the parallelism problems for you. It provides parallel iterators, manages the amount of parallelism and workload distribution, and simply just works out of the box in 99% of cases.

Here is how your problem would look if implemented through rayons parallel iterators:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::error::Error;

struct Rdr;
impl Rdr {
    fn records(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Result<StringRecord, Box<dyn Error>>> {
        [Ok(StringRecord), Ok(StringRecord), Ok(StringRecord)].into_iter()
    }
}

struct StringRecord;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SomeStruct {}

fn map_some_struct(_new_record: StringRecord) -> SomeStruct {
    let result = SomeStruct {};
    result
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let rdr = Rdr;

    let records: Vec<StringRecord> = rdr.records().collect::<Result<_, _>>()?;
    let final_result: Vec<SomeStruct> = records.into_par_iter().map(map_some_struct).collect();

    println!("{:?}", final_result);

    Ok(())
}
```

```
[SomeStruct, SomeStruct, SomeStruct]
```

Note that there might be slight differences to your actual problem because you never stated the exact return value of `Rdr::records()`. I just assumed it was an `impl Iterator`. If it's actually a `Vec` or a `&[]` slice, then the initial `.collect()` call is of course unnecessary.

If you don't want to `.collect()` first, you can directly convert the `Iterator` into a `ParIterator` via `par_bridge()`. Note, however, that this requires the type to be `Send`, but that's probably not a problem anyway.

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::error::Error;

struct Rdr;
impl Rdr {
    fn records(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Result<StringRecord, Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>>> {
        [Ok(StringRecord), Ok(StringRecord), Ok(StringRecord)].into_iter()
    }
}

struct StringRecord;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SomeStruct {}

fn map_some_struct(_new_record: StringRecord) -> SomeStruct {
    let result = SomeStruct {};
    result
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>> {
    let rdr = Rdr;

    let final_result: Vec<SomeStruct> = rdr
        .records()
        .par_bridge()
        .map(|val| val.map(map_some_struct))
        .collect::<Result<_, _>>()?;

    println!("{:?}", final_result);

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```rust
> let mut data: Vec<SomeStruct> = Vec::new();
> ```

You expect `data` to be `Vec<SomeStruct>`, but when you call

```rust
data.push(thread::spawn(move || -> SomeStruct { ... }));
```

you push `JoinHandle<SomeStruct>`. [`JoinHandle`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#) is a handle to the thread you  spawned. When you call the [`JoinHandle::join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.join) method, you wait for your thread to finish its computation (creating `SomeStruct` in your case) and extract the returned object. `join` returns `Result<SomeStruct>`, because your thread could have paniced. If the thread panics, an error is returned. You do the thread joining and error handling in your call here:

> ```rust
> let final_result = data.iter().map(|c| c.join().unwrap());
> ```

All you have to do is change the type of `data` to `Vec<JoinHandle<SomeStruct>>` and your program should work. See [`std::thread::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) to see the return type and for more information.

Comment: Then I need one more loop to extract SomeStruct and conversion to Vec<SomeStruct>, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what `final_result` does. Calling `.iter()` gives you an iterator over your threads and `.map(...)` waits for each thread to finish and unwraps its result. If you want to continue with a `Vec<SomeStruct>`, all you need to do is calling `.collect()` after `.map(...)`: `let final_result: Vec<SomeStruct> = data.iter().map(|c| c.join().unwrap()).collect();`. There is a chapter in the Rust book explaining iterators in more detail: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-02-iterators.html.